# Python3 xml parsing and information extracting with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've to parse an XML file which contains a setup for a software I have to rewrite. Unfortunately I'm quite unfamiliar with XML parsing and all tutorials I've found so far only cover ridiculously simple use cases. The structure of that XML file is as follows:

```
<department name="R&D">
    <section name="Prototyping">
        <room name="A.2.25">
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123456"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123556"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="654321"/>
            <machine name="Omron X-Ray" serial="X235-566"/>
        </room>
    </section>
</department>
```

The real list is much longer, contains much more machines, rooms and sections. Now the problem: I have to put all of those attributes into different PyQt5 combo boxes, but they depend on each other. So when the user selects "R&D" in the first combo box, the appropriate sections ("Prototyping" in my example, but there are actually more) should be visible and selectable in the 2nd combo box. And depending on the section the user has chosen in the 2nd combo box, the appropriate entries in the 3rd combo box should appear etc. Every room has different machines.

I'm desperately trying to use ElementTree to solve this problem but I'm really getting stuck. I have tried it for two days now and don't find a solution. Maybe there's a better parser than ElementTree? Maybe here's an expert who can help ...

Thanks (a million) in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml2dict can help here

```
import pprint
import xmltodict

xml = '''<r><department name="RnD">
    <section name="Prototyping">
        <room name="A.2.25">
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123456"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123556"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="654321"/>
            <machine name="Omron X-Ray" serial="X235-566"/>
        </room>
    </section>
    <department name="Oper">
    <section name="SectionName">
        <room name="A.2.25">
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123456"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123556"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="654321"/>
            <machine name="Omron X-Ray" serial="X235-566"/>
        </room>
        <room name="A.2.251">
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123456"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="123556"/>
            <machine name="Yamaha YSM" serial="654321"/>
            <machine name="Omron X-Ray" serial="X235-566"/>
        </room>
    </section>
</department>
</department></r>'''
data = xmltodict.parse(xml)
pprint.pprint(data)
print(data['r']['department']['@name'])
```